# BTC stuck with 0 confirmations

Tags: blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

I sent Bitcoin from my Copy Wallet 3 days ago but it has still 0 confirmations.
I only paid 1% Fee so around 50 sat/Byte, it worked last time took around 6 hours but it still worked.
Now they are stuck for more than 3 days.
Is there anything I can do?

TxID: 91bf90a4cd33d82e35d9ef7450792891d2483fe50284f1a8e617d8b02a1a3a86
Address: 1NuQPHkTaomES5FBTkzWUHKRAtKK8XveFm

Comment: 44,9 sat/byte actually

Answer (score 1):

I stopped looking when i saw 50 sat/B. That's currently too low.
Can you bump that up a bit using RBF? Or wait a bit more until the mem pool empties out some.

Also you should be aware that fees are not related to the amount you are sending. They are an absolute value, not a percentage.